# jquery what the best way to reset every positioning to default?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few thumbnails upon clicked, it will display all the works of the user, for example user 1 have 1 work, user 2 have 6 works. By right i will be showing the div accordingly to how many works the user have. If i click on user 1, it show 1 work, i exit and click on user 2, instead of 6 works it show 1 only, because the function takes on what was set on user1, as i didn't reset.. So i wonder if there is a best practices for resetting the show/hide div back to default upon exit, the only solution i know of now is calling the .show each time the function activates, but doesn't seem to be a good way to do things. Please advise

Example

```
$(function() {
    $(".img_thumb_holder").on('click', function() { 
        var index = $(this).index(); // get current index of clicked thumbnail, so i can call out the related name from captionArray via same index

        // what i did to solve the reseting, forcing it to show out each time the function runs
        $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({id: idArray[index]}), // pass the name of clicked holder into php to query
            url: "CMS/PHP/retrieveAuthorWorks.php",
            success: function(data) {   
                console.log("Array consist of " + data)
                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').removeAttr("src");
                linksArray=[];  
                titleArray=[];  
                descArray=[];   
                $(".full_image_desc .title").html(data[0].title);
                $(".full_image_desc .info").html(data[0].desc);
                $('.portfolio_thumbImg_holder img').each(function(index, element) {                                                     
                      if (data[index]) {
                          linksArray.push("http://localhost/testdatabase/cms/" + data[index].links);
                          $(element).attr("src", linksArray[index]);
                          titleArray.push(data[index].title);
                          $(element).attr("title", titleArray[index]);
                          descArray.push(data[index].desc);
                          $(element).attr("desc", descArray[index]);
                        }
                }); 
                // check how many divs without the image data, and hide it
                $(".portfolio_thumbImg_holder img:not([src])").parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: pls post code as example to what your talking about

Comment: @doniyor done updated